# Suggestions for improvement of a water heating control system

Tags: design, heat

I have improved my heating controls circuit design and would like some feedback on how to prevent the operator from temporarily energizing the circuit when a coil is de-energized because of a loose connection. More details on this in #7.

The system to be heated is a 30,000 gallon water basin. A pump draws water out of the basin, which then flows through an immersion heater bank and back into the basin.

Overview of the circuit:

1. The system has an overtemperature controller (OT20) and process controller (TIC188). OT20 looks at the heater banks and faults in case there is an overtemperature condition in the heaters. TIC188 monitors the water basin and sends a 4-20mA output to the step controller (SC93) which turns heater banks ON and OFF based on how far the water temperature is from the setpoint. So if the setpoint is 25 and PV is 10, all 4 heaters will be ON; if the PV is 22, only 1 heater will be ON.
2. CR11 is system enable and is energized if the flow, float switches and ESTOP CR01 are okay, OT20 isn't faulted, Drive isn't faulted (CR75 is closed), and CR40 (system health monitor) relay is energized.
3. The purpose of CR40 is to ensure that the system only starts up when the operator holds down the (illuminated) pushbutton LT33. If there is ever a fault, the system stays in fault till the fault clears and the operator intentionally starts the system back up.
4. The NC contact of the OT20 energizes CR35 whose NC contact is a permissive for the "system enable" relay. During normal operation, NO contact of OT20 is made and NC is open. If the controller is faulted, CR35 will be energized and its NC contact will open and drop CR11. CR35 is also used for fault indication. The NO of OT20 is the enable for SC93.
5. TD15 is a timing relay that waits a few seconds for the flow switch to pick up before changing state to OPEN. If the pump fails and the flow switch doesn't detect any flow after a set time, NC of TD15 opens and drops CR11.
6. In case of an emergency, the operator can push CR01 which cuts off power to CR11 and SC93. I know I could have just cut off power to CR11 and achieved the same result.
7. CR17 is energized as long as the drive is in run mode (drive run contact CR72). If the drive is in run mode, then and only then will OT20 have power on its COM pin. Seems to be a decent safety measure, however, there is a glitch here: notice that if there is a loose connection between the Drive and the control panel that cuts power to coil CR17, causing the system to fault out, the operator can temporarily energize the system by holding down LT33 while the fault is still there. The heaters obviously won't run but the Drive and the pump will. I do not want the system to pick up if there is a fault of any kind, in this case a loose or a cut wire that cuts power off to CR17. I cannot find a way around this. We could use an NO contact of CR17 as a permissive for CR11 by having another pushbutton that would bypass that contact during startup. I can see this being tiresome for the operator. I'd like some feedback on this.

[image: Drawing 1]
[image: Drawing 3]
[image: Drawing 5]

Comment: Solar water heating?

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: Can you  draw a state diagram, showing gains and delays and phaseshifts, etc?

Comment: You seem to know what you want to prevent. Given the substantial overall cost, adding a few sensors and relays or similar that identify specific fault conditions seems easy and useful.

Comment: going to PID control could accelerate the settling time VS the proportional control you describe.

Comment: @SolarMike no this is an immersion heater bank. Resistive heating.

Comment: @DaveTweed I have taken your feedback into consideration and modified my post so that it only addresses a single issue as opposed to being an open-ended question.